# Opening a DB2 Database

Tags: database, db2

I tried using C-Express, maybe it's just my lack of knowledge on how to use it but I cannot seem to open this *.db2 database I have on my PC. If someone could explain to me what application and what steps I need to take to completely view the database it would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you say `*.db2`, are you saying that you have file(s) on your system with the extension `.db2` that you don't know how to use?

Comment: Correct, I know it is a database and anything I've pulled up has told me to use C-Express from IBM but I am unable to figure out how to open it. The contents aren't readable when opened in a regular word processor.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single file that you can "open" using DB2 Express-C. Your file must belong to some other application, possibly dBase II.